# Export html table to excel with text , images and radio button in Angular 8 using javascript or typescript or jquery

Tags: javascript, angular8, export-to-excel

This question is asked several times, but the solution provided as PHPExcel is now deprecated.

1. [export table html to excel with text and images by javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30434372/export-table-html-to-excel-with-text-and-images-by-javascript)
2. [Javascript - export image into excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43925959/javascript-export-image-into-excel)
3. [Export HTML table to excel with text and images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500323/export-html-table-to-excel-with-text-and-images)

None of them worked for me. I can only export text.

Comment: Try displaying you table with datatables (a javascript library for tables with large data). It has a plugin for exporting table to pdf or excel and even printing

Comment: IIma check out the demo and documentation via this link 
https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/simple.html

it's a free library, let me know if you have any issues

Comment: I am having this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49322350/data-table-integrated-with-angular-not-showing-export-buttons-such-as-excel-pdf/51167065

Comment: Have you resolved the issue now ☺️

Comment: no,have not solved it yet